# Bayesian Network, computing probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I'm a bit confused about bayesian networks when in a situation like the one
in the figure below section 4, we want to compute $P(M)$ given the probability tables:

[image]

Now, if I understand it right the probability of $M$ is just the joint probability :
$P(M) = P(M| G, S)P(G)P(S)$ = $0.90 \cdot 0.20 \cdot 0.90$

Is that right? or should I sum of all entries of the table $P(M|G, S) $

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the total law of probability to consider all cases.

$$P(M)=\sum_{s,g} P(M|G=g,S=s)P(G=g)P(S=s)$$

Comment: Thank you, should I consider s,m,g or just m, g (here it won't make any effect because we have one entry in each table of $(G, S$ )? and isn't that the case where we have hidden variables

Comment: I made a typo, the sum should be over $g$ and $s$. Here the value of $m$ is fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much